# Linux route cache shows high RTT for loopback - is it normal?

Tags: linux, routing, ip-routing, iproute2

Here are parts of route cache from three different servers that are **NOT** under high load.

```
# ip route show cache | grep -B 1 rtt

local 127.0.0.1 from 127.0.0.1 dev lo 
    cache <local>  mtu 16436 rtt 106ms rttvar 155ms cwnd 7 advmss 16396 hoplimit 64
...
local 127.0.0.1 from 127.0.0.1 dev lo 
    cache <local>  mtu 16436 rtt 145ms rttvar 130ms cwnd 6 advmss 16396 hoplimit 64
...
local 127.0.0.1 from 127.0.0.1 dev lo 
    cache <local>  mtu 16436 rtt 172ms rttvar 205ms cwnd 5 advmss 16396 hoplimit 64
```

Why may be rtt so high and so noisy (rttvar is quite high too) ? How can I interpret these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values below 200 msec (TCP_RTO_MIN) for the RTT are meaningless. Values below 250 msec for the rttvar are meaningless (because the other side may not have timers that are sufficiently accurate). The RTT/RTTVAR measurements are irrelevant on such fast interfaces.

From `include/net/tcp.h`:

```
#define TCP_RTO_MIN     ((unsigned)(HZ/5))
```

From `net/ipv4/tcp_input.c`:

```
     * 1. If rtt variance happened to be less 50msec, it is hallucination.
     *    It cannot be less due to utterly erratic ACK generation made
     *    at least by solaris and freebsd.
```